# `if` branch with owned and borrowed value without let binding

Tags: rust, ownership

I have this `if` statement where both branches have to return a `&HashMap<..>`. In one of the branches though I have an owned `HashMap` and the other one I'm accessing one from a reference to some struct. Currently, I'm being forced to define an unbound `let` variable outside the `if` block to hold the owned map from the first branch (otherwise it would be freed at the end of the `if` block and the reference would be invalid).

```rust
struct Descriptor {
    env: HashMap<String, String>
}

fn merge_env(_a: &HashMap<..>, _b: &HashMap<..>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
    todo!()
}

fn example(d1: &Descriptor, d2: &Descriptor, feature_on: bool) {
    // Can I somehow avoid having to declare this?
    let holder;
    let env = if feature_on {
        holder = merge_env(&d1.env, &d2.env);
        &holder
    } else {
        &d1.env
    };
    read_env(&env);
}

fn read_env(_env: &HashMap<String, String>) { todo!() }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c7e5031319c82be1d654394fa779fff)

Is there way to do this avoiding the unbound `let`? Maybe some wrapper that can hold both an owned and borrowed value? Also, is the current way idiomatic?

Comment: Might be able to use `std::borrow::Cow` but IMO the variable is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables have scope in rust. Once their scope ends, they are de-allocated. Thus if you declare your `holder` inside the `if` like that:

```
if feature_on {
        let holder = merge_env(&d1.env, &d2.env);
        &holder
} 

// holder has already been dropped at that point. It would be "use after free" error to use it here
```

It would be impossible to use it outside the `if` block, because it would have been dropped at that point. Thus you must make sure that the owned object lives long enough.

One of the possible solutions is what you have already done - by moving the owning variable before the `if` you have guaranteed that the holder instance will not be dealocated , thus avoiding the [use after free](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Using_freed_memory) error.

The other solution is to use the enum [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), which has two variants - `Cow::Borrowed` - for holding references and `Cow::Owned` for holding the actual instance. This perfectly fits your use case:

```rust
fn example(d1: &Descriptor, d2: &Descriptor, feature_on: bool) {
    let env =  if feature_on {
        Cow::Owned(merge_env(&d1.env, &d2.env))
    } else {
        Cow::Borrowed(&d1.env)
    };
    read_env(&env);
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know `Cow` could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor `holder` to be an `Option` and have the `None` case be what is currently your else-branch. Then, a second variable can be a ref into that `Option` or to an argument (type annotations are not needed, just for explanation):

```rust
fn example(d1: &Descriptor, d2: &Descriptor, feature_on: bool) {
    let holder: Option<HashMap<_, _>> = feature_on.then(|| merge_env(&d1.env, &d2.env));
    let env: &HashMap<_, _> = holder.as_ref().unwrap_or(&d1.env);
    read_env(env);
}
```

If you really want to get rid of the temporary variable, you can inline all of this:

```rust
fn example(d1: &Descriptor, d2: &Descriptor, feature_on: bool) {
    read_env(
        feature_on
            .then(|| merge_env(&d1.env, &d2.env))
            .as_ref()
            .unwrap_or(&d1.env),
    );
}
```

Considering the "is this idiomatic": I would say, that your current code is absolutely fine too.